# Wipe out iOS device

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdocumentdirectory

This is something first phase requirement I needed for my application.

I want to design a WIPE-OUT application,
This application will WIPE-OUT all the data.

I want a flow like this:

1. Install our WIPE-OUT app from AppStore
2. This app will have access to Documents directory (like in Android have access to File Manager)
3. User can delete, rename and move the files of document directory (using our application)
4. Those files are anything (PDF or word file downloaded from Mail, Photos from camera of FB or anything)
5. In short same FileManager app which will have access to my iPhone storage and I can delete the data which is in non-recoverable.

As per my knowledge,
it is not possible.

My question is,

1. Is it possible in some other way and will apple approve the app?
2. If it is not possible, then please share me link for the same.

Comment: it is NOT possible due security reasons and sandboxing of iOS

Comment: Not possible as all documents for individual apps are in their own app directory, and apple won't approve any attempt to get at them.

Comment: Yes, not possible got it.
But any link which will mention this is welcome

Comment: You can make such an application and distribute for jailbroken devices, that'll work.

Comment: Also, doesn't iOS already have this functionality? It's available on any iPhone or iPad in the settings.  
Settings > General > Reset > Erase All Content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments it is not possible.

This [Apple Guideline](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) will actually be responsible for the rejection

### 2.6 Apps that read or write data outside its designated container area will be rejected

Comment: Small correction: It is possible if you build an app without sandboxing.
Although yes, it will be rejected. You can only run such apps on jail broken devices.

Answer (score 1):

Apple does have a MDM (Mobile Device Management) SDK that they don't talk about a lot. You need to be on an Enterprise Developer Account, and you'll end up signing a non-disclosure agreement.

https://www.apple.com/iphone/business/it/management.html

This SDK allows remote wipe. MaaS360 and Lotus Traveler can do it. But if you aren't a Fortune 500 company, odds are good you'll never see it.